# Unable to load background image for lightning:button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

the below code is not rendering as expected. Can someone help me what is the mistake here.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <aura:attribute name="car" type="Object" access="public"
                    default="{'sObjectType' : 'Car__c',
                              'Name' : 'Manish Choudhari',
                              'Picture__c' : '/resource/cars/luxury/ford_mustang.jpeg'}" />
    <lightning:button variant="Neutral" class="tile">    
        <div style="{# 'background-image:url (' + v.car.Picture__c + ')'}" class="innertile">
            <div class="lower-third">    
                <h1 class="slds-truncate">{!v.car.Contact__r.Name}</h1>
            </div>        
        </div>    
    </lightning:button>

</aura:component>
```

I have updated the static resource file too. But the page is not rendering as expected. This is happening in both standalone application or in app builder.
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting in console log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the tile class in .css file and sorted out

Answer (score 0):

1. There is issue in getting **Picture__c** field in div style.
2. I feel you have to change type of car object also. Instead of object data type, you should use **Car__c**

Change code like below. It should resolve your issue.

```
<aura:attribute name="car" type="Car__c" access="public"
                        default="{'sObjectType' : 'Car__c',
                                  'Name' : 'Manish Choudhari',
                                  'Picture__c' : '/resource/cars/luxury/ford_mustang.jpeg'}" />
        <lightning:button variant="Neutral" class="tile">    
            <div style="{! 'background-image:url (' + v.car.Picture__c + ')'}" class="innertile">
                <div class="lower-third">    
                    <h1 class="slds-truncate">{!v.car.Contact__r.Name}</h1>
                </div>        
            </div>    
</lightning:button>
```

Comment: i tried by changing the both but no luck.

Comment: instead of contact__r.name can you hardcode value and try.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. In aura component we dont have `sObjectType` or `SObjectType`. It is `sobjectType`. Ofcourse this will not make any difference for getting image, its required when sending the object to apex for create or update.
2. Data type Object has a bug in lightning aura component. So use `sObject` or `Car__c`.
3. You need to define other properties like no-repeat, width and cover.
4. Neutral button will inherit padding, so use base variant

   ```
   <aura:attribute name="car" type="sObject" access="public"
                   default="{'sobjectType' : 'Car__c',
                            'Name' : 'Manish Choudhari',
                            'Picture__c' : 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252_960_720.jpg'}" />


   <lightning:button variant="base" class="tile" >
       <div style="{!'background: url(' + v.car.Picture__c +') no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: cover;width:6rem;'}">
           {!v.car.Name}
       </div>
   </lightning:button>
   ```

Comment: no-repeat, width, cover i specified in style class. tried changing the button also.. Somehow the issue is with
style="{! 'background-image:url (' + v.car.Picture__c + ')'}"

Comment: can you show the updated code in question. @KrishnaN